# Cannot run JBoss 5.0.1 GA application on IDEA 10.5

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss5.x

I am trying to run simple hello world JBoss 5.0.1 GA application on IDEA 10.5 and it fails with an error  but when using IDEA 11 (trial) it is working as expected.

Any idea why (pun not intended)?

Error from the console:

```
[2012-11-19 01:07:20,890] Artifact JbossHelloWorld:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

[2012-11-19 01:07:20,901] Artifact JbossHelloWorld:war: Artifact is not deployed. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment

[2012-11-19 01:07:20,957] Artifact JbossHelloWorld:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

13:07:21,162 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
```

Error from the idea log:

```
2012-11-19 12:58:31,194 [2899991]  DEBUG - min.JavaeeAgentAdminServerBase -    
javax.management.MBeanException  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:184)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:165)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
    at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.InvokerAdaptorService.invoke(InvokerAdaptorService.java:270)  
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor302.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:138)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:140)  
    at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.SerializableInterceptor.invoke(SerializableInterceptor.java:74)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)  
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFactory.java:180)  
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor301.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)  
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)  
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:855)  
    at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:422)  
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor300.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)  
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)  
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)  
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)  
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)  
Caused by: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy: file:/D:/projects/JbossHelloWorld/out/artifacts/JbossHelloWorld_war/JbossHelloWorld.war  
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:838)  
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)  
    ... 45 more  
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JbossHelloWorld.war doesn't exist. (rootURI: file:/D:/projects/JbossHelloWorld/out/artifacts/JbossHelloWorld_war/JbossHelloWorld.war, file: /D:/projects/JbossHelloWorld/out/artifacts/JbossHelloWorld_war/JbossHelloWorld.war)  
    at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.file.FileSystemContext.getRoot(FileSystemContext.java:209)  
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.getRoot(VFS.java:304)  
    at org.jboss.virtual.VFS.createNewRoot(VFS.java:262)  
    at org.jboss.

deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:826)  
        ... 49 more
```

Comment: Can you verify that artifact is built correctly and `D:/projects/JbossHelloWorld/out/artifacts/JbossHelloWorld_war/JbossHelloWorld.war` is present on the disk? Does it work if you deploy this file manually? Could it be that some external tool is affecting the war file, like an antivirus?

Comment: The war file is present on the disk. I cannot shut down the antivirus.

Comment: You can try to configure the antivirus to ignore your project and IDEA system directory. You also didn't answer to the question about deploying this war manually.